# In App Purchase Code Crashing during testing

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, unrecognized-selector

I have added InApp Purchasing to my app but when trying to complete a test transaction using a Test User account, the app keeps crashing at the following code saying that Unrecognised Selector sent to Instance.

I have read up about this and feel it may be something to do with the fact I am using Auto Renewal Subscription product.

The code that seems to be related to the crash is this line:

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"TransCancel" object: self];
```

I have provided my InAppPurchase code incase anyone can please please help me with this!!

**InAppPurchaseSS.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import  "StoreKit/StoreKit.h"

#define kProductPurchasedNotification       @"ProductPurchased"
#define kProductPurchaseFailedNotification  @"ProductPurchaseFailed"
#define kProductPurchaseCancelledNotification  @"ProductPurchaseCancelled"

@interface InAppPurchaseSS : NSObject <SKProductsRequestDelegate,SKPaymentTransactionObserver,UIAlertViewDelegate>
{
    SKProductsRequest*   productsRequest;
    SKProduct *proUpgradeProduct;
    UIAlertView* waitingAlert;
    BOOL isTransactionOngoing;
}

@property (retain) SKProductsRequest*   productsRequest;
@property (retain) NSArray * products;
@property (retain) SKProductsRequest *request;
@property (assign) BOOL isTransactionOngoing;

+ (InAppPurchaseSS *) sharedHelper;

-(id)init;
- (void)buyProductIdentifier:(NSString *)productIdentifier;
- (BOOL)canMakePurchases;
-(void)restoreInAppPurchase;
- (void)collectProducts;
@end
```

**InAppPurchaseSS.m**

```
#import "InAppPurchaseSS.h"
#import "Reachability.h"

@implementation InAppPurchaseSS

@synthesize products;
@synthesize request;
@synthesize productsRequest;
@synthesize isTransactionOngoing;

static InAppPurchaseSS * _sharedHelper;

+ (InAppPurchaseSS *) sharedHelper {

    if (_sharedHelper != nil) {
        return _sharedHelper;
    }
    _sharedHelper = [[InAppPurchaseSS alloc] init];

    return _sharedHelper;

}

-(id)init {

    if( (self=[super init]))
    {
        isTransactionOngoing=NO;
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];

    }

    return self;

}

- (void)collectProducts
{
    self.request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:@"my.inappads"]];
    self.request.delegate = self;
    [self.request start];
}

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
    NSLog(@"Received products results...");
    self.products = response.products;
    self.request = nil;    
    NSLog(@"Number of product:%i : %@",[response.products count],response.products);
    NSArray *product = response.products;
    proUpgradeProduct = [product count] == 1 ? [[product firstObject] retain] : nil;
    if (proUpgradeProduct)
    {
        NSLog(@"Product title: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.localizedTitle);
        NSLog(@"Product description: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.localizedDescription);
        NSLog(@"Product price: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.price);
        NSLog(@"Product id: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.productIdentifier);
    }

    for (NSString *invalidProductId in response.invalidProductIdentifiers)
    {
        NSLog(@"Invalid product id: %@" , invalidProductId);
    }
}



-(void)restoreInAppPurchase
{
    Reachability *reach = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    NetworkStatus netStatus = [reach currentReachabilityStatus];    
    if (netStatus == NotReachable) {        
        NSLog(@"No internet connection!");   
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Internet"  message:@"Sorry, no internet connection found"   delegate:nil  cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil] show];
        return;
    }
    waitingAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Restoring..."  message:@"Please Wait...\n\n" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [waitingAlert show];

    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}




- (void)buyProductIdentifier:(NSString *)productIdentifier {

    if ([productIdentifier isEqual: @"my.inappads"]) {
        NSLog(@"No IAP Product ID specified");
        return;
    }

    Reachability *reach = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection]; 
    NetworkStatus netStatus = [reach currentReachabilityStatus];    
    if (netStatus == NotReachable) {        
        NSLog(@"No internet connection!");   

        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Internet" message:@"Sorry, no internet connection found"  delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil] show];
        return;
    } 
     isTransactionOngoing=YES;

    waitingAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Purchasing..." message:@"Please Wait...\n\n" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [waitingAlert show];

    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 6.0) {
        SKMutablePayment *payment = [[SKMutablePayment alloc] init];
        payment.productIdentifier = productIdentifier;
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
    }
    else {
        SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:productIdentifier];
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
    }
}



-(void)enableFeature
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"PurchaseSuccess"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

}


- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:(NSError *)error
{

    [waitingAlert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"Restore completed transaction failed");

}

- (BOOL)canMakePurchases
{
    return [SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments];
}

//
- (void)finishTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction wasSuccessful:(BOOL)wasSuccessful
{
    isTransactionOngoing=NO;
    [waitingAlert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];

    // remove the transaction from the payment queue.
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];

    if (wasSuccessful)
    {
        [self enableFeature];

        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Congratulations!!" message:@"You have succesfully Purchases." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil] show];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"successbuy" object:self];
    }
    else
    {
      [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error!" message:transaction.error.localizedDescription  delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil] show];

        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"TransCancel" object: self];
    }
}


- (void)completeTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
    NSLog(@"succesfull transaction");
    [self finishTransaction:transaction wasSuccessful:YES];
}

- (void)restoreTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
    NSLog(@"transaction is restored");
    [self finishTransaction:transaction wasSuccessful:YES];
}


// called when a transaction has failed
- (void)failedTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
    isTransactionOngoing=NO;

    NSLog(@"failed transaction called");

    if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled)
    {
        NSLog(@"Transaction failed called");
        NSLog(@"Transaction error: %@", transaction.error.localizedDescription);

        [self finishTransaction:transaction wasSuccessful:NO];
    }
    else
    {
        [waitingAlert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
        NSLog(@"user cancel transaction");
        // this is fine, the user just cancelled, so don’t notify
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"TransCancel" object: self];
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
    }
}



#pragma mark -
#pragma mark SKPaymentTransactionObserver methods

// called when the transaction status is updated
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    NSLog(@"transaction status updated");
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [self completeTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                [self failedTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
} 

- (void) dealloc
{
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] removeTransactionObserver:self];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

I am using the @TransCancel in the view that the user makes the purchase in, the code is like this:

// Purchase

```
NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];

[center addObserver: self  selector: @selector(TransactionCancel)  name:@"TransCancel" object: nil];
[center addObserver: self selector: @selector(TransactionComplete)  name:@"successbuy" object: nil];
NSLog(@"%d",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"PurchaseSuccess"]);
if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"PurchaseSuccess"])
    btn.hidden=YES;
else
    btn.hidden=NO;
```

**Error Log**

```
2014-01-06 00:25:40.694 MyApp[2764:60b] transaction status updated
2014-01-06 00:25:40.695 MyApp[2764:60b] failed transaction called
2014-01-06 00:25:40.696 MyApp[2764:60b] Transaction failed called
2014-01-06 00:25:40.696 MyApp[2764:60b] Transaction error: Cannot connect to iTunes Store
2014-01-06 00:25:40.730 MyApp[2764:60b] -[MyViewController TransactionCancel]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1666a350
```

**MyViewController**

```
#import "UpgradeViewController.h"
#import "ECSlidingViewController.h"
#import "MenuViewController.h"

#import "InAppPurchaseSS.h"

#define ProductIdentifier @"<my.inappads>"

@interface UpgradeViewController ()
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet JSAnimatedImagesView *animatedImagesView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *installFullAppButton;
@end

@implementation UpgradeViewController
@synthesize menuBtn, animatedImagesView = _animatedImagesView, scrolly, bannerView, labelPrice;




- (NSString *)publisherIdForAdSdkBannerView:(AdSdkBannerView *)banner {
    return @"e0616d4190bff65279ed5c20de1b5653";
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Price
    SKProduct *product = [[[InAppPurchaseSS sharedHelper] products] lastObject];
    NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [numberFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
    [numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    [numberFormatter setLocale:product.priceLocale];
    NSString *formattedString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:product.price];
//    [self.installFullAppButton setTitle:formattedString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    labelPrice.text = formattedString;

    // Purchase

    NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];

    [center addObserver: self  selector: @selector(TransactionCancel)  name:@"TransactionCancel" object: nil];
    [center addObserver: self selector: @selector(TransactionComplete)  name:@"successbuy" object: nil];
    NSLog(@"%d",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"PurchaseSuccess"]);
    if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"PurchaseSuccess"])
        btn.hidden=YES;
    else
        btn.hidden=NO;



    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.




    //UIScrollView

    self.scrolly.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 600);

    //Image Transition

//    self.animatedImagesView.delegate = self;


    self.view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.75f;
    self.view.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0f;
    self.view.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;


    if (![self.slidingViewController.underLeftViewController isKindOfClass:[MenuViewController class]]) {
        self.slidingViewController.underLeftViewController  = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Menu"];
    }


    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.slidingViewController.panGesture];

    self.menuBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    menuBtn.frame = CGRectMake(8, 30, 34, 24);
[menuBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menuButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [menuBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(revealMenu:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


    [self.view addSubview:self.menuBtn];


    myWebView.opaque = NO;
    myWebView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)revealMenu:(id)sender
{
    [self.slidingViewController anchorTopViewTo:ECRight];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    self.screenName = @"Upgrade";
}


#pragma mark - Memory Management

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
//    [self setAnimatedImagesView:nil];
    [self setScrolly:nil];
//    [self setAnimatedImagesView:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
     [self setBannerView:nil];

    [super viewDidUnload];
}


- (void)dealloc
{
    bannerView.delegate = nil;

}



-(IBAction)but:(id)sender
{
    [[InAppPurchaseSS sharedHelper] buyProductIdentifier:ProductIdentifier];
}

-(IBAction)restore:(id)sender
{
    [[InAppPurchaseSS sharedHelper] restoreInAppPurchase];
}

- (IBAction)dismissView:(id)sender {

     [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}

-(void)TransactionComplete
{
    btn.hidden=YES;
}
-(void)TransactionCancel
{
    btn.hidden=NO;
}
```

Comment: Are you subscribing to the `TransCancel` notification anywhere? If so, make sure you're providing a valid selector in `addObserver:selector:name:object:`.

Comment: You need to post the exact and complete error message. And you need to point out the exact line of code causing the problem. So far you seem to be guessing which line it is. The crash stack trace will tell you the exact line.

Comment: @jonahb I am using the TransCancel notification in the viewController where the user makes the purchase. I have edited my answer to show this, please let me know if I am doing something wrong

Comment: And does that view controller have an instance method `TransactionCancel`?

Comment: @jonahb Yes, lik this -(void)TransactionCancel
{
    btn.hidden=NO;
}

Comment: Show the exception message and stack trace...

Comment: I have edited my answer with the error log if that helps! I'm seriously stuck :(

Comment: Where's your implementation of the `TransactionCancel` method? That's the problem. You register that method for the `TransCancel` notification but you don't implement the method.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks for your help, that seemed to solve the crash but now Im getting Transaction error: Cannot connect to iTunes Store although Im using a test user account. Any idea why this may be?

Answer (score 0):

You have this line:

```
[center addObserver: self  selector: @selector(TransactionCancel)  name:@"TransCancel" object: nil];
```

Which means that `self` must implement the `TransactionCancel` method. The error indicates that the method doesn't exist on the `MyViewController` class.

The solution is to add the `TransactionCancel` method to the `MyViewController` class.

Comment: The method does exist on that class as I've shown above. It presents like this -(void)TransactionCancel { btn.hidden=NO; } - am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The error clearly states that the `MyViewController` class does not have a method named `TransactionCancel`. You have not shown that method anywhere in your question. In fact, you did not show anything related to your `MyViewController` class, just your `InAppPurchaseSS` class.

Comment: I edited my answer with that ViewController code as well. Please see

Comment: That's the code for the `UpgradeViewController` class, not the `MyViewController` class. See the `@implementation` line.

Comment: It's the same thing, I edited UpgrdeViewController to MyViewController when I pasted the code into Stack, so yes its the same thing but im getting Error! Cannot Connect to iTunes Store

Comment: Your question is about the unrecognized selector error. Is that fixed or not now? I'm unclear where you are on that. If you have another issue you should ask a separate question focusing just on that other issue. Also, when posting code in a question, only post relevant code. No need to post your entire class.

Comment: I have posted another question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20955452/cannot-connect-to-itunes-store-in-app-purchase-error