# Cannot connect to iTunes Store In App Purchase Error

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have setup In App Purchases in my app, the code all seems fine, you can see this thread for reference of my code:

[In App Purchase Code Crashing during testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940518/in-app-purchase-code-crashing-during-testing)

The problem Im having is that when trying to user a Test Account to make a purchase, I am getting the following error every time:

```
2014-01-06 13:38:33.806 MyApp[3361:60b] failed transaction called
2014-01-06 13:38:33.806 MyApp[3361:60b] Transaction failed called
2014-01-06 13:38:33.807 MyApp[3361:60b] Transaction error: Cannot connect to iTunes Store
```

Anyone else having this issue? Anything you could suggest?

If it helps, my product is an Auto Renewable product, although i don't think that should make a difference...